# Using Intent while saving data of previous Activity

Tags: android, android-intent

I'm currently trying to guess how do I save a data from a previous Activity.
An example is:

At the startPage.class, I have a few options to choose from(Animation Mode, Image Mode, Text Mode) so if I choose for example Text Mode so the it'll be the `RadioButton3` and when I press next it goes to the another Activity. So lets say in that new Activity it has this Intent command. How do I retain the data from the previous activity when I press the `backSelection3`?
Meaning, when I press the back, I want the `RadioButton3` to be the selection still instead of it resetting to the default choice.

```
backButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent backSelection3 = new Intent(imagemode64by64.this, startPage.class);
        startActivity(backSelection3);
    }
});
```

Comment: Use [Shared Preference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html) or a [Database](http://www.learn-android-easily.com/2013/07/sqlitedatabase-in-android.html) to save the state of your variables.

Comment: Use Intent putExtra to wrap the messages. And use startActivityForResult() rather than using startActivity().

Comment: have you search anything before asking question?

Comment: @HemantChandDungriyal - yes. I've tried to research but have yet to found anything that I can understand.

Comment: @symphony888 i dnt think so bcz hulk and nun'e already answer of you question.

Comment: @HemantChandDungriyal well you said before asking question. but their replies are after I asked the question. So I'm replying to "before asking question"

Comment: @symphony888 for your kind info if u search any think then u differently search which above mentioned by hulk and nun'e

Comment: @HemantChandDungriyal im not here to argue at all. I'm here to ask question because I'm not sure about a specific thing. You there being an ignorant guy just pinning and -repping me makes me think you're look down on people who don't know about Android. I don't even know what the are these saving things called therefore I asked a question here to know it better. If you're just here to pin me down and not contribute, I suggest you bug off. Thanks

Comment: @Hulk - hey Thanks, I'll check about it.

Comment: @Nun'eChai Ill check about it and try to understand. Thanks mate

Comment: I would suggest you look into @Nun'eChai's suggestion. I am not convinced, Hulk's suggestion fit's your requirement. This here is a nice _little_ tutorial covering quite a few storage options: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidFileBasedPersistence/article.html

Comment: @Siddharth Lele: Can i ask why? I agree shared Preference and database is also a good way. But if we are moving around within activities then using intent and as i mentioned to use startActivityForResult is also a good way. in onActivityResult() you will get all things from which activity you came back and set here the radio button fields. Then why making the things complex using database for this kind of short things.
We are saving only views state so i asked to use these things. If we need to something store large things that cannot use by intent then definitely we should go for database.

Comment: @Hulk: **1:** I did not suggest using a Database. **2:**: `startActivityForResult()` is used when you expect a result from the next activity. The OP's requirement state no such thing. An enterprise app of mine has over 200 Activities, but I **do not** use `startActivityForResult()` in all of them because it does not serve the purpose. And finally, **3:** The OP states he want's to save the `RadioButton` that was selected. This line here says it all: _How do I retain the data from the previous activity when I press the backSelection3?_ Hence, I am not convinced your suggestion is valid.

Comment: @Hulk: In fact, Alex has provided an even simpler solution in his answer. Rendering, my suggestion, your suggestion and Nun's suggestion moot. Interestingly, his own answer is quite the opposite of his comment. ;-)

Comment: @SiddharthLele: right! Alex gave also a good suggestion. There are several ways to save at all. We should check the way to fit in our requirement.

Comment: @Hulk: Lol. Agreed. Let's save it. One question at a time. ;-)

Comment: @SiddharthLele: Alex showed a way to moving around the data. He is also using intents. Thats what i said to use intent in different way. As i said several ways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [onSaveInstanceState](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onSaveInstanceState%28android.os.Bundle%29)

```
void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle out) {
   String val = ...
   out.putString("MYVALUE", val);
   super.onSaveInstanceState(val);
}
```

Then

```
void onCreate(Bundle savedState) {
   if(savedState != null) {
       String val = savedState.getString("MYVALUE");
  }
}
```

Or do you mean how to put data for another activity? Then you can do

```
Intent i = new Intnet(this, OtherActivity.class);
String val = ...
i.putExtra("MYVALUE", val);
startActivity(i);

Then in the other activity

void onCreate(Bundle savedState) {
   ...
    Intent i = getIntent();
    String val = i.getStringExtra("MYVALUE");
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Here is an age old example of passing data between classes:

```
class A{

        static int num = 0; 

        public void setNum(int number){

            num = number 

        }

    }



class B{
            public static void main(){
                A obja = new A();
                obja.setNum(3);

            } 
        }
```

As soon as you do the operation in class B you can use the num variable in class A.

Comment: The question was Android specific. The provided example can not be used in Android as is.

Comment: Lol this was primarily meant to clear the concept of message passing. If the OP cant make out this simple construct of code, it would be better to get well versed with some basics. Although I do not agree with you, but I stand by you for your right to say so :)